# How to avoid Left join table show duplicate row?

Tags: mysql

I have some problem with the query issue when trying to sum up the quantity.

Table

This cart item table stored id_cart and id product

[image]

This order table stored id_cart and other id may be included such as supplier. This table is used to track order record and send notification to supplier.

[image]

Wrong result. Expected output = 1, 1, 1

[image]

```
SELECT  id, id_product, SUM(qty) 
from cart_item 
left join Orderp using(id_cart) 
group by id_product
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07bf57/1

The issue caused by duplicate id_cart in order table as well. How can i handle this? Any solution to make it works? Thanks.

Comment: Based on the data, the result is exactly as it should be. You have two orders referring to the same cart, so the two products in those orders would total 2. the 3rd order only has one item, so it totals to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  i.id_product,
  p.name productname,
  b.id_branch,
  b.branchname,
  SUM(i.qty)
from cart_item i
left join (SELECT DISTINCT id_cart,id_branch FROM Orderp) o on o.id_cart=i.id_cart
left join product p on i.id_product=p.id_product
left join catalog c on c.id_product=p.id_product and c.id_branch=o.id_branch
left join branch b on b.id_branch=o.id_branch
group by
  i.id_product,
  p.name,
  b.id_branch,
  b.branchname
```

The main problem in `Orderp` table because it containts two different orders for one cart (`DISTINCT id_cart,id_branch` helps here). And you need to use the second condition by `id_branch` for `catalog` (`and c.id_branch=o.id_branch`).

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32d5f/16

And I think you can use everywhere `INNER JOIN` instead `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
  i.id_product,
  p.name productname,
  b.id_branch,
  b.branchname,
  SUM(i.qty)
from cart_item i
join (SELECT DISTINCT id_cart,id_branch FROM Orderp) o on o.id_cart=i.id_cart
join product p on i.id_product=p.id_product
join catalog c on c.id_product=p.id_product and c.id_branch=o.id_branch
join branch b on b.id_branch=o.id_branch
group by
  i.id_product,
  p.name,
  b.id_branch,
  b.branchname
```

Comment: After select distinct id_cart from orderp, if want to left join another table which consist of id_product then duplicate happen again. I can simply distinct id_product but when i need some field in the table then duplicated row will happen again.

Comment: @Crazy - Could you make a new demo in SQL Fiddle with another table? And please show all the columns in your query what you want to get in the result. I think you can add it into your question.

Comment: This is my new build query, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32d5f/2 , the expected result is 1,1,1 but it shows 2,2,2 after join catalog.

Comment: @Crazy - I updated my answer. The main problem in `Orderp` table becouse it containts two different orders for one cart. And you need to use the second condition by `id_branch` for `catalog`. Hope it'll help you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32d5f/16

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in your data, or in your data model

```
INSERT INTO OrderP(`id_order`,`id_cart`)VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO OrderP(`id_order`,`id_cart`)VALUES(2, 1);
```

There are 2 rows for id_cart = 1, so the "natural join" will double every row when joining cart_item to orderp.

Using an inner join to a different column in orderp works better because now there is only one row in orederp for each cart_item.

```
SELECT id_product, sum(qty)
from cart_item ci
left join Orderp o on ci.id_cart = o.id_order
GROUP BY id_product
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07bf57/13

Comment: This worked fine without where clause, how if there's condition? The result will return 0 record.

Comment: @Crazy - I think here used a wrong condition - "ci.id_cart = o.id_order".

Comment: @Leran2002 It might work if without where clause, if there's a where clause then will be 0 record.

Comment: @Learn2002 the change of column in thr join us feliberate,  not an accident. There is an explanation for why.